# RoR: Disable DB queries in log

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, logging

Is there a way to disable MONGODB logs in the rails development.log file?

Currently running rails 3.2.7 with Mongoid as the driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mongoid 2.2+, you can set it in the mongoid.yml file like so:

```
development:
  ...
  logger: false
```

Not sure if that still works in mongoid 3. You might want to specify your mongoid version.